# SQL Server 2008 Full text search stopwords

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have row values like "shop.it", "shop.com" for a column

When I do full text search by shop, I can get "shop.com" but not "shop.it".

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Please help me on the same

Comment: Can you include the query you're using?

Comment: Hi, I got the solution by modifying the database property.  Thanks

Comment: @Ashok it would be really helpful if you explain what property did you modify?